# How to Force WebBrowser Control to use New Session or clear sessions

Tags: c#, vb.net, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, browser-cache

In my application, user will open multiple tabs by clicking on menus.
Each tab is dynamically created and containing **webbrowser control** to load URL.

Each URL point to same server and some of URL does not have access so , gives `Resource not have access` error received.

Now, problem is, example- If user directly click on `Menu3` and related tab loaded with webbrowser URL and follow to next, URL contain other popup link then it works and able to popup the URL.

Now, user click on `Menu5` where not have access so, get this error `Resource not have access` (denied from server`). Its fine.
NOw, again URL reach to`Menu3`and try to open sub link to popup dialog then it gives`403 forbidden error- decline access`. It works initially but, later it just giving this error.

As it looks, I need to clear the `WebBrowser Control` cache or forcely start with new session.

Can any one please guide me how to force **WebBrowser** to start new session or remove earlier caches ?

Answer (score 6):

The cache of the WebBrowser control is the same of Internet Explorer. You have various options:

1) Completely clear that cache (will also clear Internet Explorer!):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24401521/2633161

2) Use some tags in the server response:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

3) Use a random query string to force the refresh:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://www.example.com/?refresh=' & Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
```

4) Force refresh of the page (this will load the page 2 times!):

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://www.example.com/')
WebBrowser1.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely)
```

Comment: method 3 is the simplest

Comment: What are the implications of #3 and #4? Are you just stashing cookies for 100000 instances?

Answer (score 6):

There is a better alternative. It's using the WinINet.DLL and calling SetInternetOptions

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int lpdwBufferLength);

    private const int INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION = 42;

InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

This will end the browser's session cache. After you call this method the webbrowser control will forget whatever sessions had in memory