# Is it possible to log in to more than one account in the facebook.com with WebBrowser in C# Windows Application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-applications, webbrowser-control

I have created a c# windows application, with 3 Webbrowser that I want to open 3 different facebook.com/instagram.com accounts to view the home feed of all accounts in one application.

But when I log in to one account in webbrowser1, then webbrowser2 and webbrowser3 also logging into the first account(maybe by setting a cookie or other options). Is there any way to prevent setting cookies or managing any other setting/option in Webbrowser to solve this problem?

[image]

As you can see, All Webbroswers opening the same account as the first one when I'm logging in one of the browsers!

Comment: I am not 100% if it is possible with the built-in webbrowser control, you need to enable some type of "InPrivate" or "incongnito" for each control to accomplish this, at least easily. It has been many years ago since I had done this....

Answer (score 1):

probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050047/how-to-force-webbrowser-control-to-use-new-session-or-clear-sessions) will help you.

You will need to have different sessions on the browsers.